# What does the Perl substitution operator act on?

Tags: regex, perl, substitution

I have been programming in Perl, off and on, for years now, although only sporadically is it my primary language. Because I often go months without writing any perl, I rely heavily on my dog-eared Camel Book to remind me how to do things. However, when I copy recipes verbatim with no understanding, this bothers me. This is one of the most vexing: On page 154 of the 3rd edition Camel, there is an example for "modifying strings *en passant*, which reads like this:

```
($lotr = $hobbit) =~ s/Bilbo/Frodo/g;
```

Q1) what is going on here? On what, exactly, is the regex operating?

Q2) Is this near-magical syntax necessary for such a basic operation as "take a string from $a, modify it with a regex, place result in $b"?

Q3) How do I do this operation using the loop default variable as the initial string?

Apologies in advance to Perl dreamers for whom the above looks perfectly natural.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Hmmm... `($lotr=$hobbit) =~ s/Bilbo/Frodo/g` is one of the many magicks of Perl. Now for some answers.

Q1) `$lotr` is being assigned the value contained in `$hobbit`. After the assignment, we can forget about the source variable. Treat `($lotr = $hobbit)` as it's own statement as-if we had written:

```
$lotr = $hobbit;
$lotr =~ s/Bilbo/Frodo/g;
```

instead. The regex is operating on `$lotr`.

Q2) The syntax is simply a one-line version of the snippet given above. Think of it as "copy the string from `$a`, copy it into `$b`, and modify `$b` with the regex" instead of "take a string from `$a`, modify it with a regex, place result in `$b`"

Q3) I'm assuming that you mean the default pattern searching space by "loop default variable"? In that case, just use `$_` instead of `$hobbit`:

```
while (<>) {
  chomp;
  ($lotr = $_) =~ s/Bilbo/Frodo/g;
  print "\$lotr = [$lotr]\n";
  print "\$_    = [$_]\n";
}
```

Interestingly enough, the magic var `$_` is not modified by this operation. This is how you can conclude that the assignment happens *before* the regex substitution and that the substitution does not interact on the default pattern space in any way.

And for the experienced Perl programmers thing... I don't know too many people that are thrown by some piece of Perl syntax regardless of how long they have been staring at it 'cept Mr. Schwartz of course ;)

Comment: That answer is correct. I was typing it as this was posted. It( the solution) by the way took me one Google search to find.

Comment: @D.Shawley. Jees mate. From what you said above, why would $_ be modified? "copy the string from $a ($_) ... into $b ($lotr) and modify $b ($lotr) with the regex, place the result in $b ($lotr)". No magic involved with $_ at all.

Comment: Thank you, Mr. Shawley. I have been using IDL a lot, and IDL has no in-place operators-- everything is $y=f($x). That grammar had become a mental habit, which was preventing me from grokking elementary Perl. Thanks for the unlock.

Comment: @Rob -- hehehe... for some reason I _always_ expect that Perl slips in `$_` when you aren't looking ;)

Answer (score 5):

Different languages do different things with the assignment operator.  In some, it is a statement, not an expression, so can't be combined into a larger expression.  In some, it returns the value assigned, but only as a value (often called an rvalue), not as something that itself can be modified or assigned (an lvalue).  An example of this is C, where you
can write:

```
 a = b = c;  # assign value of c to b and a
```

but not:

```
 ++(b = a);  # assign value of a to b, then increment b
```

And in some, the result of an assignment is the lvalue assigned to.  (In Perl, this applies only to scalar assignments; list assignments are a more complex beast.)  So you can do ++($b=$a) or ($b=$a) =~ s/a/b/ or any other operation that expects an lvalue on the assignment, and it will first do the assignment and then further modify the lvalue assigned to.

Comment: Thanks, it's good to know that the syntax of the example, while not magical, is Perl-specific.

Answer (score 1):

If in Q2 you mean to take a sub-string from $a, you might find this idiom useful:

```
($b) = $a =~ /(substring-to-match)/;
$b =~ s/regex-on-susbtring/result-string/;
```

Also do note that $a and $b are not normal variables in Perl since they have special scope rules related to the sort function.  See 'perldoc perlvar' for details.